# CSS: no hovering if selected

Tags: css, hover, focus, css-selectors

For the most it sounds quite simple, but I'm new in this stuff.

```
input.input-text:hover {color:red}
input.input-text:focus {color:blue}
```

I want if `input-text` is focused it must not become red on hovering.  Can we do that?

Comment: You could also use the :not() selector in some cases. http://www.w3schools.com/css3/default.asp and http://www.w3schools.com/css/default.asp

Comment: This should work as intended without modification. If it's both focused and hovered, focus will take precedence because it appears last (and both selectors have the same specificity).

Comment: Your current code should work as you are describing. Tested in IE9, FF, and Chrome: http://jsfiddle.net/jXLtR/

Comment: Please test out my answer, thank you.

Comment: Jon, Shmiddty, thanks guys, my fault!!!! Works:)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can stack pseudos

```
input.input-text:focus:hover {
  color:green;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use jquery to accomplish this because you are trying to conditionally set css. You can leave your css like it is, then add this on your html page

```
$("input.input-text:focus").hover().css('color', 'black');
```

If you haven't included the jquery script, add this to the head of the document:

```
 <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```